# Boot issues on Inspiron M5010 when installing 64 bit Ububtu 14.04. Help!

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, system-installation, dell

This is my first time using Ubuntu. I bought a wiped computer from ebay and I'm just trying to install Ubuntu OS.  I downloaded the software, formatted my USB to Fat 32.  I used UUI and Yumi both to extract the files and build a bootable USB.  My RAM is 2048, so it should be enough to run the 64 bit.  I've checked my boot order several times to make sure its correct!  But, after creating a boot stick twice, I keep getting the same "Boot Error"  "Media test failure, check cable"  "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

Help!  I have no clue.  I don't know if its a hardware issue, if I missed a step creating the boot stick, or if I am trying to install something not compatible.  It would be very helpful to provide a step by step for Windows switchers!!  Because otherwise you are simply talking an entirely different language to me.  Open stacks and other stuff that I have never heard of.  I really like the idea of switching everything to Linux!  I even consider myself fairly technologically savvy, but I have no familiarity with this stuff and its a little disheartening. And what is grub?

Comment: The "check cable" message it's weird... are you sure the computer is not trying to boot trough the network interface? Check the bios configuration to see the boot order. Also, if it's a usb problem, you could just burn the ubuntu iso to a dvd and boot from disk.

Comment: Check this.. http://superuser.com/a/772841

Comment: My boot order is USB, Hard drive, diskette drive, CD/DVD drive, etc.  The version I downloaded is too large for the CD.  There really should be no reason it shouldn't work!  Super frustrating.

Comment: I had problems before with some USB's not being able to boot, it depends on the computer. The image is too big for a CD but not for a DVD. The only thing you could try is boot another computer with the same USB,(and cancelling before the install starts), if you get the same error you'll know that the problem is in the usb not being bootable. I use unetbootin to create bootable usb's and it seems to work well most of the time.

Comment: Well, I'm going to try UNetbootin and get the file right from there. If that doesn't work, not sure what i will do.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, check whether the downloaded ISO was correctly downloaded: check the md5sum on the PC/OS you downloaded the ISO from. `md5sum NameOfYourIso.iso` under Linux, `md5sums NameOfYourIso.iso` under Windows and then compare the string you've got to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes